# how to handle errors like 404 / 500 in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, ruby-on-rails-3

Hey, I hope you can help me.

I am trying to find a way to direct the user to the default error pages 404.html and 500.html in my public folder.

So when there is a routing or nomethod error it should be directed there to.
I already tried some stuff in my application controller but it didnt work.

Many thanks!!

Comment: I thought putting 404.htm and 500.htm to public folder is ok. But I'm not sure.

Comment: I got those in there by default. But they dont show up if errors occur

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Rails does this for you automatically when running in production mode. When you upload your application to a live server, Rails takes care of handling those exceptions and rendering the correct error pages with the correct header status. If you're trying to see what those pages look like (for testing or something), just access them directly via `http://localhost:3000/404.html`

Whenever you set up your Rails application on a live server (let's use Apache as an example), you give the site root as the `/public` folder in your application. Then, whenever a request is made to that server address, Apache first looks in that public folder and tries to serve a static asset (this is a configurable option in `[environment].rb`). If it can't find the requested page, then the request is forwarded through the Ruby stack.

When in production mode, if Rails encounters an error that isn't handled (i.e begin, rescue), it throws the error the whole way up to the stack, which then tells Apache (again, in my example) to render an appropriate error.

Here are some common errors that you'll see in development mode and what they render in production mode:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => 404 (page not found)
nil.method => 500 (server error) unless you turn off whiny nils
ActionController::RoutingError => 404 (page not found)
```

Comment: @DannyRe - I've added more to my answer that you might find helpful

Answer (score 2):

Happens automatically if run in production mode - no need that you do that manually.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [this post](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/36-rails-3-0-rescue-from-routing-error-solution) to redirect all requests causing a Routing Error.