# How can Rails automatically rescue from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in development mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rescue

I am using the following piece of code on my `ApplicationController` :

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :not_found

def not_found
  render :nothing => true, :status => :not_found
end
```

in order make Rails respond with correct status code and not raise an exception 
in *development* mode.

I know that [how-to-handle-errors-like-404-500-in-rails3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4640472/658469) explains how Rails works in production mode. In other words, what I am trying to do in development mode is done without any piece of code in production mode.

How can I make development mode behave like production mode and get rid of the above piece of code?

Note that I am using `Rails 3.2.3`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you want to turn this off?:

```
config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
```

This is set to `true` in `config/environments/development.rb` by default.

Comment: Thank you. I believe your answer is the correct one and I will accept it. Can you please add that one has to delete file "public/404.html" in your answer? This makes the answer even more accurate to the question, since in my current code I render nothing => true.

Comment: Let me research the subject some more.

Comment: any news on this? Did you research the subject?